# counterexample to universal quantification being the right adjoint of substitution?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

I have two definitions that seem equivalent of existential and universal quantifications as left and right adjoints of subsitution [1]. But I seem to have a counterexample...

So first for the definition take a function $f: A \to B$ then this induces a function or even a functor $$ f^{-1}: \mathcal P(B) \to \mathcal P(A)$$  and two
other functors from  $\mathcal P(A)$ to  $\mathcal P(B)$ defined by

- $\exists_f(X) = \{y: \exists x(x \in X \wedge f(x) = y)\}$
- $\forall_f(X) = \{y: \forall x(f(x) = y \implies x \in X)\}$.

where the fact that these are left and right adjoints is given by the equation

- $\exists_f(X) \subseteq Y \iff X ⊆ f^{−1}(Y)$
- $f^{−1}(Y) \subseteq X \iff Y ⊆ \forall_f(X)$

Now I thought I'd take a simple example consisting of two types one containing people P = {A, E, B} with names N = {Adam, Αδάμ, Eve} B being a little baby boy that has not yet been given a name. So we have

f = { Adam ↦ A, Αδάμ ↦ A, Eve ↦ E }

and hence

$f^{-1}$={{} ↦ {},
     {A} ↦ {Adam, Αδάμ}, {E} ↦ {Eve}, {B} ↦ {}, 
{A, B} ↦ {Adam, Αδάμ}, {B, E} ↦ {Eve}, {A,E} ↦ {Adam, Αδάμ, Eve},
 
     {A, E, B} ↦ {Adam, Αδάμ, Eve} }

$\exists_f$ = {{} ↦ {},
  {Adam} ↦ {A}, {Αδάμ} ↦ {A}, {Eve} ↦ {E},
{Adam, Αδάμ} ↦ {A}, {Adam, Eve} ↦ {A, E}, {Αδάμ, Eve} ↦ {A, E},
{Adam, Αδάμ, Eve} ↦ {A, E}
    }

$\forall_f$ = {{} ↦ {},
   {Adam} ↦ {}, {Αδάμ} ↦ {}, {Eve} ↦ {E}, 
{Adam, Αδάμ} ↦ {A}, {Adam, Eve} ↦ {E}, {Αδάμ, Eve} ↦ {E}, 
{Adam, Αδάμ, Eve} ↦ {A, E}}

But then we have the following counterexample to the adjunction it seems.
Take the property Male = {A, B}

$f^{-1}$(Male) = {Adam, Αδάμ} ⊆ {Adam, Αδάμ}  $\iff$  Male ⊆  $\forall_f${Adam, Αδάμ} = {A}

but clearly {A, B} ⊈ {B}

So where have I gone wrong here?

[1] I am coming at this from reading the article "Categorical Logic and Model Theory" in "Categories for the Working Philosopher" edited by Elaine Landry. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RIM8DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA113&ots=VLJLR-Mn50&lr&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q&f=false
The other is defined here on Stack Exchange in the answer to the question  [Right-adjoint to the inverse image functor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915417/right-adjoint-to-the-inverse-image-functor)

Comment: is ther a simple way to add newlines in my equations? I could make them more readable if so.

Comment: Yes: use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and then you have lots of nice options for controlling the layout. (\\ will give you a newline, if that's all you need).

Comment: <br> also works for linebreak.

Comment: @Berci: please don't encourage people not to use MathJax!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't calculated $\forall_f(\{\mathrm{Adam}, A\delta\alpha\mu\})$ correctly. $\forall x (f(x) = B \implies x \in X)$ is true for any $X$ because there are no $x$ such that $f(x) = B$, so $B \in \forall_f(X)$ for any $X$.

Comment: so it should be:
 
∀f = {{} ↦ {B},
{Adam} ↦ {B}, {Αδάμ} ↦ {B}, {Eve} ↦ {E,B},
{Adam, Αδάμ} ↦ {A,B}, {Adam, Eve} ↦ {E,B}, {Αδάμ, Eve} ↦ {E,B},
{Adam, Αδάμ, Eve} ↦ {A, E,B}} 

and so

$f^{-1}$(Male) = {Adam, Αδάμ} ⊆ {Adam, Αδάμ}   <=>  Male ⊆  ∀f{Adam, Αδάμ} = {A,B}

yes, that would work.

Comment: That looks right to me.